# Correct way to use __setattr__ to listen for current_url changes in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a navigation companion based on Python Selenium and I need to trigger a function every time 'driver.currenturl' changes. But I believe I'm not using **setattr** correctly. This is raising a recursion error: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". Any tips?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class Browser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
        driver.start_client()
        self.url = driver.current_url.lower()

    def whenChanged(self):
        print('changed')

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.key = value
        self.whenChanged()

def init():
    browser = Browser()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Comment: Using `super().__setattr__(key, value)` will avoid the recursion but whether it'll end up doing what you want... *shrugs*

Comment: As @Jon Clements said use super but you must inherit the webdriver first...